# jQuery - slideToggle, links continue to slide up and down

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have some menu items slide down when a user hovers on an image, then hide when they move the cursor away from the image and/or the menu items. The problem is, if the user isn't really, really accurate when they move the mouse to a menu item, the menu items will slide up, and down, and up... and down.

Is there a way to get this working so that once the menu items appear, they will remain in place until the user "mouses out" of either the main image, or the link items below the image?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/yHMQV/1/). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there is a spacing issue which causes this - between the image/bucket and the children.

Comment: @Evan I removed the padding but still see the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the hover events from propagating when called on the `.slideBucket` children.  You'll need to also position the slideBucket up so that it overlaps the bucket and a mouseleave is not triggered.  And then manually do the slideUp on the slideBucket.  Adding a `.stop(true, true)` also helps clean up the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/yHMQV/9/

```
$(".bucket").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.slideBucket').stop(true, true).slideToggle('400');
}).children('.slideBucket').hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).slideUp(400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that looks closer. If you mouseout from a list item the menu doesn't disappear.

Comment: @MarkB - Ya, it wasn't quite as easy as I first thought.  Still not too bad to fix though, check my updated answer and jsFiddle.

Comment: I'm thinking there is something wrong with the foundation of this menu. I've seen these work well online, so I may scrap it and start over or try to find a plugin somewhere. I've wasted hours on this already. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panda2005/s5CUe/)
hover actually takes two functions :-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".bucket").hover(  
        function(){  
            $(this).children('.slideBucket').slideDown('400');  
        },  
        function(){  
            $(this).children('.slideBucket').slideUp('400');  
        }  
    );  
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Kostas. I'm slowly convincing myself that the versions of slide() aren't what I want. Sometimes after I hover out of the image, the menus continue to slide up and down 1-2 more times. Sometimes it works perfectly. Sometimes if I trigger the dropDowns and then hover out the menu stays visible...